# Línea de "límite" horizontal en chartjs

Tags: jquery, chart.js

Estoy haciendo una gráfica y necesito hacer que me ponga una línea horizontal en X punto de la misma

este es el "script" de mi gráfica;

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
  var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, ],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'Reparaciones x dia',
        data: ['0', '4', '1', '3', '1', '0', '0', '1', '11', '4', '8', '7', '5', '1', '2', '5', '3', '8', '1', ],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,51,0.5)"
      }, {
        label: 'Totales',
        data: [0, 4, 5, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 21, 25, 33, 40, 45, 50, 51, 53, 58, 61, 69, 73],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(0,153,255,0.5)"
      }]
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Necesito una línea por ejemplo en el número 15 del eje vertical...

Comment: Estoy intentado reproducir tu gráfica y no consigo que se  dibuje, se te ve a ti correctamente?

Comment: A mi sí que me genera la gráfica. De todos modos voy a volver a copiar el código por si acaso hay algún error.

Comment: @PavloB. Tu código no está completo, faltan cosas como la etiqueta `</script>` de cierre, y la inclusión del `chart.js`. Ahora mismo no es reproducible

Comment: @PavloB. Estoy trabajando actualmente con Chart.js de hecho puedo reproducir sin problema tu ejemplo https://i.stack.imgur.com/jSKME.png pero no entiendo a que te refieres con una linea? podrías ser más especifico? – Jorgesys

Comment: PavloB. me parece que la respuesta de @AlvaroMontoro está más que completa. Podrías marcar la pregunta como resuelta.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Puedes crear tu propio plugin para Chart.js, que dibujará en la gráfica la línea que quieras. Por ejemplo, si quieres que el plugin dibuje una línea horizontal en el valor de `y`, el código debe seguir el siguiente algoritmo:

- Añadir una opción con el valor de `y` en el que quieres mostrar la línea horizontal (esto se haría dentro de `options` cuando creas el Chart)
- Crear un plugin que haga lo siguiente:

  - Detecte si se ha pasado un valor para dibujar la línea horizontal
  - Calcular la altura a la que se debe dibujar la línea dentro de la gráfica
  - Posicionarse a esa altura en la posición x=0 (con `moveTo`)
  - Crear una línea hasta x=ancho de la gráfica (con `lineTo`)
  - Especificar el color de la línea (con `style`)
  - Dibujar la línea (con `stroke`)

Luego podrías extender ese plugin para permitir más de una línea horizontal, ponerle una etiqueta a la línea, personalizar los colores, opacidad, etc... Pero me voy a limitar a la versión más básica: una sola línea de un color fijo.

Aquí puedes ver el código de este plugin funcionando:

```js
var chartPluginLineaHorizontal = {
  afterDraw: function(chartobj) {
    if (chartobj.options.lineaHorizontal) {
      var ctx = chartobj.chart.ctx;
      var valorY = chartobj.scales["y-axis-0"].getPixelForValue(chartobj.options.lineaHorizontal);
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(0, valorY);
      ctx.lineTo(chartobj.chart.width, valorY);
      ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
}
Chart.pluginService.register(chartPluginLineaHorizontal);

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, ],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Reparaciones x dia',
      data: ['0', '4', '1', '3', '1', '0', '0', '1', '11', '4', '8', '7', '5', '1', '2', '5', '3', '8', '1', ],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,51,0.5)"
    }, {
      label: 'Totales',
      data: [0, 4, 5, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 21, 25, 33, 40, 45, 50, 51, 53, 58, 61, 69, 73],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,153,255,0.5)"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    lineaHorizontal: 15
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

---

Y como extensión que ponía arriba, aquí dejo un plugin algo más complejo que te permite dibujar líneas horizontales o verticales, y además deja elegir color o etiqueta (la he hecho en poco tiempo y se puede mejorar reduciendo el código, luego la actualizo cuando tenga un poco más de tiempo):

```js
var chartPluginLineaHorizontal = {
  afterDraw: function(chartobj) {
    if (chartobj.options.lines) {
      var ctx = chartobj.chart.ctx;
      for (var idx = 0; idx < chartobj.options.lines.length; idx++) {
        var line = chartobj.options.lines[idx];
        line.iniCoord = [0,0];
        line.endCoord = [0,0];
        line.color = line.color ? line.color : "red";
        line.label = line.label ? line.label : "";
        if (line.type == "horizontal" && line.y) {
          line.iniCoord[1] = line.endCoord[1] = chartobj.scales["y-axis-0"].getPixelForValue(line.y);
          line.endCoord[0] = chartobj.chart.width;
        } else if (line.type == "vertical" && line.x) {
          line.iniCoord[0] = line.endCoord[0] = chartobj.scales["x-axis-0"].getPixelForValue(line.x);
          line.endCoord[1] = chartobj.chart.height;
        }
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(line.iniCoord[0], line.iniCoord[1]);
        ctx.lineTo(line.endCoord[0], line.endCoord[1]);
        ctx.strokeStyle = line.color;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fillStyle = line.color;
        ctx.fillText(line.label, line.iniCoord[0] + 3, line.iniCoord[1] + 3);
      }
    }
  }
}
Chart.pluginService.register(chartPluginLineaHorizontal);

var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, ],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Reparaciones x dia',
      data: ['0', '4', '1', '3', '1', '0', '0', '1', '11', '4', '8', '7', '5', '1', '2', '5', '3', '8', '1', ],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,51,0.5)"
    }, {
      label: 'Totales',
      data: [0, 4, 5, 8, 9, 9, 9, 10, 21, 25, 33, 40, 45, 50, 51, 53, 58, 61, 69, 73],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,153,255,0.5)"
    }]
  },
  options: {
    lines: [
      {
        type: "horizontal",
        y: 15,
        color: "blue",
        label: "min"
      },
      {
        type: "horizontal",
        y: 32,
        color: "red",
        label: "max"
      },
      {
        type: "vertical",
        x: 12,
        color: "green",
        label: "aux"
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 5):

Tienes que extender la librería para pintar la línea.

```js
var originalLineDraw = Chart.controllers.line.prototype.draw;
var ctx = document.getElementById('myChart').getContext('2d');

Chart.helpers.extend(Chart.controllers.line.prototype, {
  draw: function() {
    originalLineDraw.apply(this, arguments);

    var chart = this.chart;
    var ctx = chart.chart.ctx;

    var index = chart.config.data.lineAtIndex;
    if (index) {
      var xaxis = chart.scales['x-axis-0'];
      var yaxis = chart.scales['y-axis-0'];

      ctx.save();
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.moveTo(xaxis.left, yaxis.getPixelForValue(index, undefined));
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#ff0000';
      ctx.lineTo(xaxis.right, yaxis.getPixelForValue(index, undefined));
      ctx.stroke();
      ctx.restore();
    }
  }
});

new Chart(ctx,  {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, ],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'Reparaciones/día',
      data: ['0', '4', '1', '3', '1', '0', '0', '1', '11', '4', '8', '7', '5', '1', '2', '5', '3', '8', '1', ],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,255,51,0.5)"
    }, {
      label: 'Totales',
      data: [0, 4, 5, 8, 9, 9 ,9 , 10, 21, 25, 33, 40, 45, 50, 51, 53, 58, 61, 69, 68],
      backgroundColor: "rgba(0,153,255,0.5)"
    }],
    lineAtIndex: 15
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yo necesito una linea horizontal, no vertical...

Comment: Perdón, ya está editado; entendí que necesitabas representar un límite para el valor de x :P